# WinForms Unit Testing

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing

I have been given an old large WinForm application and been asked to write a unit testing project for it.

---

*Asside: The code uses .xlsx files as scripts and these scripts can be complex. My initial (standard practice) idea was to make each test atomic, however, the way the methods that required testing are invoked are complex and dependent on many other code components. So I have decided to invoke a script in order to test the required components...*

---

The code was not written with unit testing in mind and in order to invoke a test I need to first open an .xlsx file; this means my test will have the following structure:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    WorkbookSet workbookSet = Factory.GetWorkbookSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    Workbook workbook = workbookSet.Workbooks.Add();
    workbookSet.GetLock();
    try
    {
        // Open the script. 
        string testScriptPath = Path.Combine(
            Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Scripts\\Test.xlsx");
        SSGForm doc = new SSGForm();
        if (FileExists(testScriptPath))
            OpenExistingWb(ref doc, ref workbookSet, ref workbook, testScriptPath);

        // Do testing here...
    }
    finally
    {
        workbookSet.ReleaseLock();
    }
}
```

For all test we will have to have the `workbookSet`/`workbook` initalisation and `Get/ReleaseLock()` actions. In my own WPF applications, I have not come accros this problem of code replication before as I have designed the apps to be unit testable from the outset. My question is **is there an standard approach in testing of wrapping the actual test code (`// Do testing here...`) with the boiler plate?**

Of course in an actual code I could use a strategy/factory pattern with an interface or merely inject a `Func<T, T>`(or `Action` for a `void` return) into a wrapper method, but is this viable for testing?

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit. Something like:

```
private void RunTest(Action action)
{
    WorkbookSet workbookSet = Factory.GetWorkbookSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    Workbook workbook = workbookSet.Workbooks.Add();
    workbookSet.GetLock();
    try
    {
        string testScriptPath = Path.Combine(
        Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Scripts\\Test.xlsx");
        SSGForm doc = new SSGForm();
        if (Utils.FileExists(testScriptPath))
            mainRibbonForm.OpenExistingWb(ref doc, ref workbookSet, ref workbook, testScriptPath);

        // Run the test logic.
        action();
    }
    finally
    {
        workbookSet.ReleaseLock();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    RunTest(() =>
        {
            // Logic here.
        });
}
```

Comment: I'd go for injecting the function into a wrapper method.

Comment: @henginy I have provided an example in the question. This seems like a reasonable approach here - do you agree?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I had in mind. I was going to post it as answer if you hadn't edited your question to include it. Still someone might come up with a better way perhaps.

Comment: Do, it. I will accept _if_ you can demonstrate how to pass `doc` into my `action()`... Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You described the method in your question; to pass the SSGForm to your action, you can just use the `Action<T>` delegate:

```
private void RunTest(Action<SSGForm> action)
{
    WorkbookSet workbookSet = Factory.GetWorkbookSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    Workbook workbook = workbookSet.Workbooks.Add();
    workbookSet.GetLock();
    try
    {
        string testScriptPath = Path.Combine(
        Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Scripts\\Test.xlsx");
        SSGForm doc = new SSGForm();
        if (Utils.FileExists(testScriptPath))
            mainRibbonForm.OpenExistingWb(ref doc, ref workbookSet, ref workbook, testScriptPath);

        // Run the test logic.
        action(doc);
    }
    finally
    {
        workbookSet.ReleaseLock();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    RunTest(doc =>
        {
            // Logic here.
            Foo(doc);
        });
}
```